# CSS Resizing/Positioning

Tags: css

I am interested in putting a survey (using survey monkey) into a website. I want it to be in a fixed position as a side bar on the left and shrink the size of the survey box. I do not know much about CSS at all.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir='ltr' lang='en' xml:lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <div>
 <head>
    <title>
      Home
       | qfo4produce
    </title>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
    <link href='css/inuit.css' media='all' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/grid.inuit.css' media='all' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/style.css' media='all' rel='stylesheet'>
  </head>
  <body class='wrapper'>
    <div id='header'>
      <a href='index.html' rel='home'>
        <img src='images/banner.png' alt="" title='Home'>
      </a>
</div>

       <div>
    <style type="text/css">
 body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0 right-sidebar-<length> 0 left-sidebar-<length>;
 }
 div#left-sidebar{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:-30;
  iframe { width: 250px !important; }
  height:100%;
 }
 </style>
     <div id="surveyInfo"> <div><script src="http://www.surveymonkey.com/jsEmbed.aspx?sm=wtvL1HViBjWad5DOwtqu7A_3d_3d"> </script> 
</div>
    <ul class='nav'>
      <li class='first'>
        <a href='what-is-qfo.html' title='What Is QFO?'>What Is QFO?</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='team.html' title='Team'>Team</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='examples.html' title='Examples'>Examples</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='technology.html' title='Technology'>Technology</a>
      </li>
      <li class='last'>
        <a href='mailto:info@franwell.com' title='Contact'>Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a class='login' href='qfo.aspx.html' title='Login'>Login</a>
    <div id='main'>
      <p>
        <img src='images/summary.png' alt="Summary of QfO Process" />
      </p>
    </div>
     Copyright &copy; 2011
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<style>` tags are only allowed in your `<head>` section IIRC. This might be what's causing whatever problem you have, which you haven't told us. Please edit your question to state what problems you're having.

Comment: Style tags just like script tags can go anywhere in the page.   It isn't uncommon to have them in the body although not best practice IMO.

What is the behavior you are getting?  can you put up a link to the dev page?

Comment: @Brian: `<style>` in the body tag is technically not valid, `<script>` tags are. The fact that it "works" is merely browsers being forgiving, but note that `<style>/<link>` CSS anywhere but `<head>` will take a moment before it "kicks in".

Comment: Understood and agree, but as I said, they can go anywhere and still work but it isn't a good practice.  As for the op's problem having the style tag in the body shouldn't be the cause.  That was my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking and the code you have presented is extremely unclear. If you are extremely new to html/css then drawing a picture instead of trying to explain it in words often helps.

Here is an example where the sidebar is in a fixed position on the left. Fixed means that it will always be there, no matter where the page scrolls to.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bceat/

Don't make CSS declarations inside of other CSS declarations. They should each be on their own.

```
/* BAD */
div#left-sidebar{
    position:fixed;
    iframe { width: 250px !important; } 
 }

/* GOOD */
div#left-sidebar {
    position:fixed;
}
iframe { width: 250px !important; }
```

You've also declared your styles inside the body of your html. Don't do that. Declare styles between the `<head></head>` tags.

```
/* BAD */
<head>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0 right-sidebar-<length> 0 left-sidebar-<length>;
 }
 div#left-sidebar{
  position:fixed;
 }
 </style>

/* GOOD */
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
   body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0 right-sidebar-<length> 0 left-sidebar-<length>;
   }
   div#left-sidebar{
    position:fixed;
   }
   </style>
</head>
```

You also have some invalid declarations like:

```
/* right-sidebar-<length> means nothing */
padding:0 right-sidebar-<length> 0 left-sidebar-<length>;
```

I know that you are new, but you are going to have to read up on the basics of html and css. That will allow you to do two things. One is pose questions using language that other developers will understand. The second is presenting at a minimum, code that is properly formatted. That way even if your terminology is incorrect, your code can speak for you. Right now you aren't getting any answers because everything is kind of a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must create a table layout like this

```
<table width ="100%">
<tr><td></td> </tr>
<tr ><td rowspan="3"></td></tr>
your monkey servey here
<tr><td>nav content</td></tr>
<tr><td> main content</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tsk, tsk. Use table layouts for tabular data. Otherwise use `display: table; display: table-row; display: table-cell;`